# Python loop issue

Tags: python, loops

I have been taking a class at Udacity and I am onto my final project submission.

I had to create a data structure by parsing a string which is :-

> example_input="John is connected to Bryant, Debra, Walter.\ John likes
>   to play The Movie: The Game, The Legend of Corgi, Dinosaur Diner.\
>   Bryant is connected to Olive, Ollie, Freda, Mercedes.\ Bryant likes to
>   play City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma, Super Mushroom Man.\
>   Mercedes is connected to Walter, Robin, Bryant.\ Mercedes likes to
>   play The Legend of Corgi, Pirates in Java Island, Seahorse
>   Adventures.\ Olive is connected to John, Ollie.\ Olive likes to play
>   The Legend of Corgi, Starfleet Commander.\ Debra is connected to
>   Walter, Levi, Jennie, Robin.\ Debra likes to play Seven Schemers,
>   Pirates in Java Island, Dwarves and Swords.\ Walter is connected to
>   John, Levi, Bryant.\ Walter likes to play Seahorse Adventures, Ninja
>   Hamsters, Super Mushroom Man.\ Levi is connected to Ollie, John,
>   Walter.\ Levi likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Seven Schemers, City
>   Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma.\ Ollie is connected to Mercedes,
>   Freda, Bryant.\ Ollie likes to play Call of Arms, Dwarves and Swords,
>   The Movie: The Game.\ Jennie is connected to Levi, John, Freda,
>   Robin.\ Jennie likes to play Super Mushroom Man, Dinosaur Diner, Call
>   of Arms.\ Robin is connected to Ollie.\ Robin likes to play Call of
>   Arms, Dwarves and Swords.\ Freda is connected to Olive, John, Debra.\
>   Freda likes to play Starfleet Commander, Ninja Hamsters, Seahorse
>   Adventures."

Which I successfully did and my output datastructure comes out as follows:-

> [['John', ['Bryant', 'Debra', 'Walter'], ['The Movie: The Game', 'The
>   Legend of Corgi', 'Dinosaur Diner']], ['Bryant', ['Olive', 'Ollie',
>   'Freda', 'Mercedes'], ['City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma', 'Super
>   Mushroom Man']], ['Mercedes', ['Walter', 'Robin', 'Bryant'], ['The
>   Legend of Corgi', 'Pirates in Java Island', 'Seahorse Adventures']],
>   ['Olive', ['John', 'Ollie'], ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Starfleet
>   Commander']], ['Debra', ['Walter', 'Levi', 'Jennie', 'Robin'], ['Seven
>   Schemers', 'Pirates in Java Island', 'Dwarves and Swords']],
>   ['Walter', ['John', 'Levi', 'Bryant'], ['Seahorse Adventures', 'Ninja
>   Hamsters', 'Super Mushroom Man']], ['Levi', ['Ollie', 'John',
>   'Walter'], ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Seven Schemers', 'City
>   Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma']], ['Ollie', ['Mercedes', 'Freda',
>   'Bryant'], ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords', 'The Movie: The
>   Game']], ['Jennie', ['Levi', 'John', 'Freda', 'Robin'], ['Super
>   Mushroom Man', 'Dinosaur Diner', 'Call of Arms']], ['Robin',
>   ['Ollie'], ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords']], ['Freda',
>   ['Olive', 'John', 'Debra'], ['Starfleet Commander', 'Ninja Hamsters',
>   'Seahorse Adventures']]]

The problem is that I need to define a procedure which looks up connections of connections which I did but it does not runs properly. The nested loop runs only one iteration. I dont know why. I tried looping by normally and also by using range function. I also used while loop but nothing works. This is my code below:-

```
    def get_secondary_connections(network, user):
        found=False
        for entry in network:
            if entry[0]==user:
                connections=entry[1]
                found=True
        connection_of_connections=[]
        i=0
        while i <len(connections):
            for entry in network:
                if connections[i] in entry[0]:
                    connection_of_connections=connection_of_connections+entry[1]
i=i+1
        if found == True:
            return connection_of_connections
        else:
            return None
    print get_secondary_connections(net, 'John')
```

Comment: Could your prettify your output data structure? It's a pain to see how the structures are nested without newlines and indentations. You can probably just paste it into an online json formatter.

Comment: Also, your `i=i+1` lost it's indentation somehow.

Comment: instead of lists, why not use dictionaries?

Comment: no. while posting this question there was some problem with indentation already and some of the code was not being accepted so i had to do some tweaking which resulted in i being not indented properly. I must assure you that 'i=i+1' is at the right place. @ashbygeek

Comment: Umm... If its in the correct place, then the get_secondary_connections function ends the line before `i=i+1`, the `i=i+1` statement is left floating as a single instruction in whatever class or script contains that function, and the rest of the code after `i=i+1` completely breaks Python's indentation rules. So, please see the answer by AS Mackay

Comment: AS Mackay solved it. But I just do not understand why my code did not rune properly

Comment: 'def get_secondary_connections(network, user):
    found=False
    for entry in network:
        if entry[0]==user:
            connections=entry[1]
            found=True
    connection_of_connections=[]
    i=0
    while i <len(connections):
        for entry in network:
            if connections[i] in entry[0]:
                connection_of_connections=connection_of_connections+entry[1]
        i+=1
 if found == True:
     return connection_of_connections
    else:
        return None'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear from the indenting of your code how you intended to do the search, however I tested the following modified version with your data and it appears to work:

```
def get_secondary_connections(network, user):
    connection_of_connections=[]    
    for entry in network:
        if entry[0]==user:
            connections=entry[1]
            i=0
            while i < len(connections):
                connection = connections[i]
                for other_entry in network:
                    if other_entry[0] == connection:
                        for item in other_entry[1]:
                            if (item != user) and (not item in connection_of_connections):
                                connection_of_connections.append(item)
                i=i+1
    if len(connection_of_connections) > 0:
        return connection_of_connections
    else:
        return None
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: You're a life saviour man. Thanks a ton. By the way, I just was curious as to why my code did not run as I expected it to be. I might learn something that I do not know. Please teach.